# JavaScript - move array items to beginning of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, lodash

I have a SectionList that displays a list of products (with a renderSectionHeader). Each header has a star icon next it and I would like to reorder the categories onPress of that star icon. For instance if the user tap on both Cars and Buildings I would like both of those categories to move to the top.

This is my SectionList:

```
<SectionList
    sections={this.state.products}
    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.sortFavorite(section.key)}}>
            <Text>{section.key}</Text>
            <FontAwesome name="star" color="grey" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
    renderItem={({item,index}) => (
        <Text>{item.name}<Text>
    )}
/>
```

First, I created an array to store/remove the favourite categories onPress:

```
sortFavorite = (currentCategory) => {
    let items = this.state.products
    let favouriteCategories = this.state.favouriteCategories
    let index = favouriteCategories.indexOf(currentCategory)

    if(index === -1){
      for(let i =0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].key === currentCategory){
          favouriteCategories.push(
            items[i].key
          )
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      favouriteCategories.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.setState({favouriteCategories: favouriteCategories},()=>{
        // move to top of array
        const sortedCategories = _.sortBy(items, (item) => {
        const index = favouriteCategories.indexOf(item.key)
         return index == -1 ? items.length : index
        })
    })
  }
```

How can compare my array of products with my array favourite categories then re-order the array of products?

This is what my array of products looks like:

```
0: {key: "Fruits", data: Array(1)}
1: {key: "Cars", data: Array(10)}
2: {key: "Buildings", data: Array(4)}
```

This is what my array of favourite categories looks like:

```
["Cars","Buldings"]
```

I'm happy to use lodash if there is a way to do it with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by the list of categories and use the index of the category key within the favorite list to order them.

```js
const categories = [
  {key: "Fruits", data: Array(1)},
  {key: "Cars", data: Array(2)},
  {key: "Buildings", data: Array(1)},
  {key: "Blah", data: Array(1)}

];

const favoriteCatIds =  ["Buildings", "Cars"];

const sortedCategories = _.sortBy(categories, (item) => {
  const index = favoriteCatIds.indexOf(item.key);
  return index == -1 ? categories.length : index;
});

console.log(sortedCategories);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you. One last question if I may.. How would you change the colour of the star icon based on the favourite categories in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash for this, just ordinary sorting is needed

```
const favoriteCategoriesSet = new Set(favoriteCategories)
const sortedProductsTree = productsTree.sort((a, b) => favoriteCategoriesSet.has(b.key) - favoriteCategoriesSet.has(a.key))
```